# How to restrict the selection of values from combobox Extjs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

In the window for creating and editing records, I have a combobox type field

```
Ext.define('BookApp.view.Book', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.bookwindow',
width   : 450,
title: 'Book',
layout: 'fit',
autoShow: true,
modal   : true,
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [               
             {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Status',
                name: 'status',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Statuses'),
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'name',
                typeAhead: true,
                queryMode: 'remote'

            },
```

...............

Store Statuses gives records from the table with the fields: id, name, order_install, where order_install is the order of the status.

Table Statuses

id    name           order_install

23   New               1

24   In Work            2

29   Postponed          3

34   Shipped            4

31   In_transit         5

How to make that the choice of a value from the status list was limited to only one value up or down according to the order_install field?

For example: If the status of In Work, then only the statuses Postponed and New were available for selection

Comment: What is your ExtJS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

- Use store `filterBy()` method with custom filtering function.
- Because your `id` values are random, you have to get the internal position of record in store to find the prior and next record.

In the next examples `filterCombo()` is the function, that filters the store. This function is used in combobox select event. You can use it where you want. There are differences between ExtJS 4 and ExtJS 6 version, so there are two examples:

**ExtJS 4**:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    Ext.FocusManager.enable();

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['order', 'id', 'name'],
        data : [
            {"id": 23, name: "New", order_install: 1},
            {"id": 24, name: "In Work", order_install: 2},
            {"id": 29, name: "Postponed", order_install: 3},
            {"id": 34, name: "Shipped", order_install: 4},
            {"id": 31, name: "In_transit", order_install: 5}
        ]
    });

    function filterCombo(combobox, index) {
        store = combobox.getStore();
        store.clearFilter();
        store.filterBy(
            function(record) {
                if ((record.index == index - 1) || (record.index == index) || (record.index == index + 1)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        );
    };

    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose items',
        store: store,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        multiSelect: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        value: 'In Work',
        listeners: {
            'select': function (combo, records) {
                index = records[0].index;
                filterCombo(combo, index);
            },
            'render': function (combo) {
                index = combo.store.find('name', combo.getValue());
                filterCombo(combo, index);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**ExtJS 6**:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['order', 'id', 'name'],
            data : [
                {"id": 23, name: "New", order_install: 1},
                {"id": 24, name: "In Work", order_install: 2},
                {"id": 29, name: "Postponed", order_install: 3},
                {"id": 34, name: "Shipped", order_install: 4},
                {"id": 31, name: "In_transit", order_install: 5}
            ]
        });

        function filterCombo(combobox, index) {
            store = combobox.getStore();
            store.clearFilter();
            store.filterBy(
                function(record) {
                    if ((record.internalId == index - 1) || (record.internalId == index) || (record.internalId == index + 1)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
        };

        Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose items',
            store: store,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'id',
            value: '24', // Equals to "In Work"
            multiSelect: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                'select': function (combo, records) {
                    index = records.internalId;
                    filterCombo(combo, index);
                },
                'render': function (combo) {
                    index = combo.getSelection().internalId;
                    filterCombo(combo, index);
                }
            }
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: guys -  Thanks.
But how can I make the filter work just as well when there is already a set value.
In the editing form until I select a new value, the filter will not work

Comment: @Ambasador You may call this function where do you like. I call it in 'render' listener. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct and I really helped

Answer (score 0):

So i have two solutions, one to prevent selecting the combo item(but it will remain visible) and the other to hide the values you don't want to be selected(using store filters).

1) [**FIDDLE: beforeselect**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l7e)
2) [**FIDDLE: filterBy**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l7g)